# How can I view when a file is uploaded via SFTP?

Tags: linux, sftp

I want to be able to tell when someone sends a file to my server over SFTP. I can monitor general changes to the directory with `inotify`, but is there any way to only view changes to files that are placed via SFTP?

Comment: Use the log files. See [ssh - SFTP logging: is there a way? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/73319/sftp-logging-is-there-a-way)

Comment: Adding to @DavidPostill comment - you can use fail2ban to watch the logfiles in realtime and get notifications/trigger actions when messages appear in them.